javascript object validation to typescript
I am looking to convert a javascript object schema into a typescript type/ interface
I depend on a library import and I have something like
    const {Object1, Object2} = require('some/library')

class SpecialObject extends Object1 {}

SpecialObject.schema{
     property1: {type: Types.Number, default : 0}
}

I want to type SpecialObject so that I have a littlebit of control over it but Typescript wont let me do something that says "I can still perform any operation that is defined in Object1 or access any attribute in Object 1" and I ensure I have property1 in SpecialObject
Anyone has an idea about what I could do ?

Does the library have typings?

Can you clarify what you're asking? What is SpecialObject.schema{/*...*/} meant to be? What do you mean by "javascript object schema"? (There are lots of different things that a search for that turns up.) Separately: Is Object1 a constructor function? Fundamentally, if the module doesn't have type information, you can define it yourself in a some-library.d.ts file and then define your SpecialObject as a subclass adding property1 (or as an interface, it depends on whether Object1 is a constructor).

I seems that Object1 is not a constructor and the library does not have typing

yes but in this case Object1 does not have typing and it is not a constructor

I want to add more context because it seems like it is a very specific question in fact
